# $A$ is a $K$-algebra and $x$ is an indeterminate. $K[x] \otimes A \cong A[x]$ as $K$-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensors

Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra and $x$ an indeterminate. Show that $ A \otimes K[x]  \cong A[x]$ as $K$-algebras

I'm stuck. I thought the map $f: A \times K[x] \to A[x]$ given by $(a,p(x)) \mapsto ap(x)$ would work but I can't find an inverse for it. Neither can I think of another way to show that it's an isomorphism.

I think I need to add that $(a,p(x)) \mapsto ap(x)$ induces a map $a \otimes p(x) \mapsto ap(x)$ by the universal property, but then any map $A[x] \to A \otimes K[x]$ has to send a polynomial with coefficients in $A$ to some polynomial in $K[x]$ and it's not obvious how that should be done because the tensor is over $K$ and not over $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $ A[x] \to A \otimes K[x] $ by $ a\cdot x \to a \otimes x $, and extending by the universal property of the polynomial ring. (Note that $ A \otimes K[x] $ is an $ A $-algebra in the obvious way.) Now, verify that this map is an inverse to the map you defined, and you're done.

Comment: Instead of $x\rightarrow 1_A\otimes x$ you can use the map $a\cdot x\rightarrow a\otimes x$ which does not require the existence of $1_A$ and still extends to an algebra homomorphism (if I am not completely wrong).

Comment: I am not too sure about this - where would this map send $ x $ to?

Comment: If $A$ does not have the unity then there is no polynomial $x$ in $A[x]$ (more generally, the definition of a polynomial over the ring $R$ is a sequence of $R$ which is ultimately $0$. If $R$ does not have $1$ then the sequence $x = (0,1,0,0,...)$ does not belong to $R[x]$.).

Comment: I have considered this map already. Unless, I misunderstood something it fails to be the inverse. We're tensoring $K[x]$ and $A$ over $K$. Correct me if I'm wrong, but we're not allowed to move scalars in $A$ out of the tensor.

Comment: @Levent Ah, yes, of course - I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: The point where I failed and still fail to see is why $K[x] \otimes A$ is an $A$-algebra or why it's justified to say $a(1\otimes x) = (a \otimes x)$.

Comment: It is an $A$-algebra because you can define a multiplication of an element of $A\otimes K[x]$ and an element of $A$ by $a\cdot (b\otimes x)=(ab)\otimes x$. But I don't see why you need this information to prove that the map @Starfall defines is the inverse of the map you defined.

Comment: I suppose the explanation you want is this: let $ a \in A $ be any element, and define $ A \times K[x] \to A \otimes K[x] $ by $ (b, p) \to ab \otimes p $. This map is bilinear, thus it factors through to give a map $ A \otimes K[x] \to A \otimes K[x] $. Thus, multiplication by $ a $ in the sense we defined above is well defined.